# Why am I getting RenderCustomMultiChildLayoutBox object was given. Error

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

In my homepage I have a column an a row inside it.And  wrap them expanded widget as you can see .Everything is ok

This is Homepage

```
class MyHome extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyHome({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
          child: Column(
        children: [
          Row(
            children: [
              Expanded(flex: 2, child: Text("something")),
              Expanded(flex: 1, child: Text("some")),
            ],
          )
        ],
      )),
    );
  }
}
```

But if I  create  a stateless widget which has nothing but a TextFomField.and change this line
from this

```
Expanded(flex: 1, child: Text("some")),
```

to this

```
Expanded(flex: 1, child: Asd()),
```

then I get this exception "RenderFlex object was given an infinite size during layout".

So I tried to use flutter inspector to fix the problem .And this is how its looked like

> https://ibb.co/s2R38vd

And this is the Asd screen which has nothing except for one textbox

```
 return Scaffold(body: TextFormField(),);
```

Can you help plase

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have to use multiple scaffold on the same page.You can remove scaffold from `Asd` widget.

```dart
class Asd extends StatelessWidget {
  const Asd({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return TextFormField();
  }
}
```

*Another solution but dont prefer:*
Also, the issue is happening because of infinite height of `Asd` you can provide fixed height on widget.

```dart
Expanded(
  flex: 1,
  child: SizedBox(
    height: 64,
    child: Asd(),
  ),
)
```